# Getting error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

we are working on face recognition. I'm having a trouble in my for loop. It produces error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

the code

```
mycursor = connect.cursor()
cmd = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE ID = " + Id                             
cursors = mycursor.execute(cmd)
isRecordExist = 0
for row in cursors:                                                          
    isRecordExist = 1    //HERE IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR IS
if isRecordExist == 1:                                                      
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE students SET Name = ? WHERE ID = ?",(Name, Id))
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE students SET Roll = ? WHERE ID = ?",(roll, Id))
else:
    params = (Id, Name, roll)                                               
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO students(ID, Name, Roll) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", params)
connect.commit()                                                            
connect.close()
```

Error

```
Enter student's name : jom
Enter student's Roll Number : 15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shownu\Desktop\Autoattendance-Cognitive-master\add_student.py", line 33, in <module>
    insertOrUpdate(Id, name, roll)                                                  
  File "C:\Users\Shownu\Desktop\Autoattendance-Cognitive-master\add_student.py", line 19, in insertOrUpdate
    for row in cursors:                                                          
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Presumably, `cursors` is `int`.

Comment: I don't know the semantics of the db api your using, but you have only one place in your code where you iterate.  The obvious answer is that "mycursor.execute(cmd)" is returning an "int".

Comment: Why sql-concat `Id` but not the others? why not parametrize all? http://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: Originally, the import database is sqllite. I just convert in to MySQL since that is the requirement. I am new to python, so I badly need help

Comment: well based on the error `cursors` is a an `int` and not a `list`

Comment: Please [edit] the full Stacktrace Error message

Comment: How can I convert it into a list then?

Comment: Are you shure that `cursors = mycursor.execute(cmd)` returns an iterable and not an `Int`?

Comment: Id recommend to print it out first and you cannot convert an int into a list.

Comment: I expect there are many examples on the net about how to iterate through a simple MySql query in Python.  You should find one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't use the API correctly. In the Pytho DBAPI the execute call does NOT return the rows. It returns the *number* of rows affected. See e.g.

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute

for your MySQL API.

Instead, you have to iterate over the cursor object itself.

```
cmd = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE ID = " + Id                             
mycursor.execute(cmd)
for row in mycursor:
     ...
```

Comment: How? I am a newbie to python. Im sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Please specific drivers used by your code.
Example assuming an sqlite3 Db connection

```
db_conn = sqlite3.connect('mydbfile.db')
mycursor = db_conn.cursor()
```

Then

```
rows = mycursor.execute(cmd).fetchall()
for row in rows
    # Do stuff on each row
```

Comment: I'm using MYSQL as a database, not sqlite3.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html), the execute method returns `None`.

> `execute(query, vars=None)`
>
> Execute a database operation (query or command).
>
> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation. Variables are specified either with positional (%s) or named (%(name)s) placeholders. See Passing parameters to SQL queries.
>
> **The method returns None.** If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.

correct way to execute will be-

```
mycursor.execute(cmd)
for record in mycursor:
    print(record)
```

hope this solves the issue